# Swift 2 errors with slider

Tags: swift, swift2, uislider, xcode9.2

I got those errors using swift in Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b)

> 1. Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'IndexPath' and 'Float'
> 2. Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'

```
@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 50
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(indexPath * slider.value)
    return cell
}

@IBAction func sliderValueChange(_ sender: Any) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Change this line : `cell.textLabel?.text = String(indexPath.row * Int(slider.value))`

Comment: Thanks for your help, the first error is fixed now. 
The second error is still there: Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)' 
How can I fix this?

Comment: That's definitely not Swift 2 

Comment: No, its swift 4.
I wanted to tell that there are 2 errors, not that it is swift 2 

Comment: I know, the topic is ambiguous.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(slider.value * Float(indexPath.row))
    return cell

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the first error is already fixed but the second error is still there.
Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'
I think it is about this pice of code: 
@IBAction func sliderValueChange(_ sender: Any) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}

Comment: remove outlets and setup outlet again for your table view

Comment: How can I show how I created the outlets?
I removed the outlets and created them again but still the error.

Comment: Thanks, It is not needed to create an outlet for a table view.
But if you want to use the reload data function than its needed.
Now both errors are fixed